# Retrieve database with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm using this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) to retrieve database results with ajax, and its working great.

Now instead of just using one drop down box to retrieve database results I would like to add an input box as well. The results should not be displayed after the user chooses a value from the drop down box, the user needs to insert a value on the input box aswell for the result to be displayed. The result should be based on the drop down box TOGETHER with the value inserted on the input box.

You can see the php file on the example above where the sql request looks like this:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
```

I'm thinking that maybe the new sql request should look something like this:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$q=$_GET["d"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."' AND date = '".$d."'";
```

where $d represents the value from the input box.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, you just need to add variables to the ajax call:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser()
    {
    str=document.getElementById("users").value;
    txt=document.getElementById("txtinput").value;
    if (str==""||txt=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&d="+txt,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select id="users" name="users" onchange="showUser()">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtinput" onchange="showUser()"/>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And as Michael JV pointed out, always sanitize user inputs in your php

Comment: you need to add the onchange item so that it triggers the function

Comment: sorry i just saw that u had edited your answer, but its still not working.

Comment: oops, missed an id in the textfield. how's that

Comment: thanks, yeah i figured that out, looking through the code. thanks. the text input is used to enter a date. this way im now able to get the result from the date given in the text box in this format: 2010-03-31. is it possible to not enter the entire date but simply entering 2010-03 and it should show me the result for the entire month? thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll need to look at the date() functions in php, as well as what format the data is stored in. I'm not sure how > < work with dates in mysql (you may have to reformat it to do the comparison

Comment: Ok, thanks a million for your help. great support great community

Answer (score 2):

1) W3Schools examples are using absolutely terrible PHP code. For example, you copy pasted that code there and you'd probably continue using it without even noticing that it's extremely prone to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always clean user input, **always**. Otherwise, don't be alarmed when you see your database and data are gone.

2) Word 'date' is a reserved word in MySQL's dictionary. It's used to specify the data type of a column or to format a date expression for use in the query. Don't use reserved words for your column names, you'll most likely encounter an error and you'll be wondering what's going on with your code that looks ok.

3) Always test your SQL in a GUI ([SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) is my favorite) to check whether it works and if you can break it somehow based on input.

Otherwise - yes, do try your own suggestion, trial and error is the best way to learn because it'll stick with you forever.

Comment: thanks for your warning, i now learned about reserved words and sqlyog thanks to you.